# My regexp has anorexia

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get multiple key/value pairs from a string where the keys is on the left of an = character and the value on the right. So the following code

```
$line = <<END;
names='bob,jane, Alexander the Great' colors = "red,green" test= %results
END
my %hash = ($line =~ m/(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+?)/g);
for (keys %hash) { print "$_: $hash{$_}\n"; }
```

Should output
names: 'bob,jane, Alexander the Great'
colors: "red,green"
test: %results

But my regexp is just returning the first character of the value like
names: '
colors: "
and so on. If I change the second match to (.+) then it matches the whole line after the first =. Can someone fix this regexp?

Comment: To me, it is not quite clear how you want to separate the value from the next key - by space? But spaces should be ok within delimiters, no? So how do you tell when the next key starts, I believe that is part of the problem, isn't it.

Comment: Yes that's right.  If it wasn't for the spaces inside delimiters I'd just use a couple of splits.

Comment: I'm not happy about the sensitivity of your subject line. Would you consider using *early-onset dementia* or *progressive multiple sclerosis* so flippantly? Anorexia means a lot more than "a bit thin".

Comment: Those are biological disorders, not behavioural. There's a huge difference between mocking biology and behaviour and speaking as someone who actually _does_ suffer from a genetic disorder I'm not happy about your attempt to conflate the two. Take that dreck to twitter where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.+?` is non-greedy which stops once it finds a match since you're not giving any regex pattern next to non-greedy form.

```
my %hash = ($line =~ m/(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+?)(?=\h+\w+\h*=|$)/gm);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iW9hJ8/1)

`(?=\h+\w+\h*=|$)` called positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by

- `\h+` one or more horizontal spaces.
- `\w+` one or more word characters.
- `\h*` zero or more horizontal spaces.
- `=` equal symbol.
- `|` OR
- `$` End of the line anchor.

Answer (score 1):

`.+?` says match one or more non-newline characters, preferring as few as possible.

You want `.+` which matches one or more non-newline characters, preferring as many as possible.

Then it looks like you also need to stop at a matching quote, so

```
/(\w+)\s*=\s*('.+?'|".+?"|.+)/g
```

Though if spaces aren't allowed in unquoted values, you want ´\S+´ instead of ´.+´

Comment: which does what OP said: capture everything after first key/value pair

Comment: This answer did actually work for the example posted but it breaks if anything follows a non-delimited match like if test=%result came first and not last.